# How can I extract a specific number from df in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-disk-free

My aim is checking if there is still enough space on my disk, every time my script (bash) proceeds a step.

Running `df; echo $?` prints:

```
Dateisystem     1K-Blöcke    Benutzt Verfügbar Verw% Eingehängt auf
/dev/sdc4      1869858440 1680951776  93900284   95% /mnt/dd
0
```

The 0 is the result of that command.
In my case, I only want `93900284` in a variable or as the result.

I already read `man df`.

Comment: ...to mark an answer as the one that worked for you, click the checkbox next to it.

Answer (score 2):

`df --output=avail /path/to/where/you/want/to/write | tail -n 1`

BTW: bash 'returns' (in this case `0` == `success`) are exit codes, the way you phrase it it seems you try to capture that rather than the output. In that case, you [might want to read this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions).

Comment: GNU's `df` isn't the only one that'll ever be run on the Linux kernel -- busybox runs on Linux too, after all; thus, it might not hurt to include an option that works with non-GNU tools. OTOH, if you pointed the OP at the source for the relevant numbers in sysfs, there'd be no dependency on any external tool at all.

Comment: Hehe, you know, I was looking at the sysfs option but I didn't know it OTOH, and got lazy, you correctly called me on that :) Voting to close as the duplicate you found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to extract suitable field from output:

```
BASH_VAR=`df | awk '/\/dev\/sda4/{print $4;}''`
```

Comment: `grep` followed by `awk` is rarely necessary - let `awk` select both the line and the field.

Comment: BTW, shell-local variables should typically have names with at least one lowercase character. POSIX specifies environment variables with meaning to the system or shell to always have all-uppercase names; using lowercase names for your own variables means you'll never overwrite something important by accident (a risk that exists because creating a shell variable with the same name as an environment variable overwrites the latter). See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is display only available disk space, you can use the following command

```
 df -k /dev/sdc4 | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'
```

Comment: Could eliminate `tail` here by having `awk` do more work: `df -k /dev/sdc4 | awk 'NR == 2 { print $4 }'`